# how to add to an array from file in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I'm trying to read a file and add the contents of it into a list but im not sure why it is not working, i think that the the file reading part works fine however there is a problem with reading it into an array, is there maybe any way to add the contents of the file into the array line by line,

eg. contents of file:
Red
Blue
yellow

so first time it would add Red then Blue etc... instead of adding all of it at once?

This is the code i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Adding_to_array_from_file
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = 
@"C:\Users\scian\OneDrive\Documents\School\KS5\C#\Files\Adding to array from 
file.txt";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
                {
                    List<string> fileArray = new List<string>();

                    string file = "";
                    while ((file = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        fileArray.Add(file);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(fileArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through your program with a debugger. Are the lines of code you expect to be executed actually executed? (Hint: "if not file exists"? Is that what you meant to write?)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *split* each line of the file on space (tabulation) you can try *Linq*:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

... 

static void Main(string[] args) {
  string path = 
    @"C:\Users\scian\OneDrive\Documents\School\KS5\C#\Files\Adding to array from file.txt";

  List<string> fileArray = File
    .ReadLines(path)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // If you want to remove empty lines
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t'},
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToList();

  ... 
}
```

In case you want an *array*, not `List<string>`: `string[] fileArray` all you have to do is to change  `.ToList()` into `.ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

First Method: try using a StringBuilder for appending strings. And then print the StringBuilder object.ToString();
Second: Console.WriteLine(List) => Change this to a String.Join(" ", fileArray); This will create a string with the values whitespace separated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

`System.IO.File` class has in-build static function called `ReadAllLines()` to get all lines into an array.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\gmbalaa\Desktop\Test.txt";

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    var arrVal = File.ReadAllLines(path);
}
```